# How to create custom alias and where I should create it in craft?

Tags: craftcms

Is there any way by which custom alias can be created in craft . I tried and found a way to make it by plugin but wanted to make it without a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's app.php file you can create your custom aliases. Add the below-given code to your return array in the app.php file. Also, you can change the name of the alias by replacing "@testUrl".
For example:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@testUrl' => 'http://samplewebsite.com',
],
```

I think this will help you.

Thanks.